# How to store a dictionary of string keys and numpy array values in a tsv file?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, file, pickle

I have a dictionary like following in python.

```py
a = {'D1' : array([1, 2, 3]),
     'D2' : array([5,2,3]),
     ...
    }
```

I want to store this dictionary in a tsv file. I am aware about the pickle library, but currently I am not able to use it, because even before I start building this dictionary, my memory allocation is roughly 3 GB. After I create this dictionary, memory occupancy is 6.5-7 GB out of 8 GB of ram on my device. When I try to save this dictionary using `pickle.dump`, my memory gets overflowed and kernel dies.

I am not aware about any tool which can store the key value pairs dynamically in the file on secondary memory. Following code is my original code, it will give more insights.

```
import pickle
f = open('wordvecs.pickle', 'rb')
a = pickle.load(f)
```

Now when I load this file, memory of 3 GB gets occupied out of 8 GB. 
Now using this dictionary `a`, I build another dictionary called `doc_vecs` as follows :

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from tqdm import tqdm
import math

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 

doc_vecs = {}
f1 = open("preprocessed_corpus.tsv", "rt")
f2 = open('doc_vecs.tsv', 'wt')
for i in tqdm(list(range(3213833))):
    docid, url, title, content = f1.readline().split('\t')
    line = title + " " + content
    v = np.mean(np.array([a[key] for key in line.split() if key in a and key not in stop_words]), axis=0)
    if(type(v) == np.float64 and math.isnan(v)):
        continue
    doc_vecs[docid] = v

seek_posn = f1.tell()
```

At the end, store the dictionary in the file `f2`.

```
pickle.dump(doc_vecs, f2)
```

After this portion is run, my memory is almost full, and when I try to save the dictionary `doc_vecs` using pickle, my kernel dies. Is there any option here? I'd like to know if I can store the dictionary of string keys and numpy array values to a txt or tsv or pickle file.

I also tried to free the more memory by deleting `a` after `doc_vecs` is built using `del a`, bu t I do not know why it does not free any memory. I also used `gc.collect()` to be sure that any non referenced variable is not occupying any memory.

Comment: Try `a = None`?

Comment: @ScottHunter, I tried this, but it also does not free any memory.

Comment: You have `f = open(`..., never use `f` again, but do use `f1`.  Typo?

Comment: @ScottHunter, I'm sorry for the confusion, the file I'm reading from is f1 only. I've replaced that f with f2 in which I want to store my final dictionary. I've also added the script for that.

Comment: Can you close `f1`? You could re-open & `seek` later if need be.